# InvalidArgumentError- was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:1 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0,

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling, gpu

Any help would be appreciated. I am new to the tensorflow and programing in general. I am following an instruction in github (https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo3) to learn object detection by YOLO-3. after running code below.Please provide me solution Asap.

`!python train.py -c config.json`

And I received the following error:

`` tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for` operation replica_1/lambda_6/Shape: node replica_1/lambda_6/Shape (defined at /home/arasdar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748)  was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:1 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_GPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
     [[replica_1/lambda_6/Shape]] ``

Comment: Have you solved the problem？ I also go the same issue with testing keras-yolov3

Answer (score 1):

Check your config.json file, if you are only using a single GPU, you should change the "gpu" argument under "train" to "0" instead of the default "0,1"

```
"train": {
    "gpu":  "0"
}
```